# Install aerospike community server on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: aerospike, deb, ubuntu-20.04, aerospike-ce

aerospike-server-community-5.2.0.2.ubuntu20.04.x86_64.deb depends python package, but Ubuntu 20.04 support only python3 and when I’m trying to install deb package I’m getting an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aerospike-server-community: 
aerospike-server-community depends on python; however: Package python is not installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 already have python3, also I have installed `python-is-python3`, doesn't help

Comment: Something is not right indeed. I checked internally and we are planning a release that should help with some of those python dependency. It is probably looking for python2 somehow... did you try that? python3 should have worked too, though, our latest version is supposed to support both...

Comment: @Meher I have tried build by source and official release 5.2.0.2 both required python. `sudo apt-get install python` was helped, but this command installed python2

Comment: Yes, that's the current workaround... this is, as far as I understand because we are trying to support both python 2 and 3 (see https://lwn.net/Articles/780737/). I believe we will soon be dropping support for python 2 by default and this should then be straight forward.